# exit status 1 when trying to pip install cantools

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, can-bus

Whenever I try to pip install cantools==34.0.0 (on python 2.7)
i receive the error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support
in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting cantools==34.0.0
  Using cached cantools-34.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting diskcache
  Using cached diskcache-5.0.2.tar.gz (47 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\bla\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-4or8zd\\diskcache\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\
users\\bla\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-4or8zd\\diskcache\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"
'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'c:\users\bla\appdata\local\temp\pip-pip-egg-info-mxhtc0'
         cwd: c:\users\bla\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-4or8zd\diskcache\
    Complete output (10 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\bla\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-4or8zd\diskcache\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import diskcache
      File "diskcache\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
        from .core import (
      File "diskcache\core.py", line 434
        raise ValueError('disk must subclass diskcache.Disk') from None
                                                                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anyone please help me? It seems like it happens when it tries to install the package diskcache

Comment: Can you use Python3 instead? It's really the better way to go nowadays, especially since Python2 has gone EOL.  I just tested and both versions 34 and 35 of "cantools" install successfully under Py3.7 and Py3.8.

Comment: According to the [cantools docs](https://cantools.readthedocs.io/en/latest): 'Python 2 support is deprecated as Python 3 has better unicode support.'

Comment: @Gary02127 Unfortunately no, this is some legacy code that is still using python 2, this does work on another machine but i'm unable to install the package on my machine

Comment: @MauriceMeyer That's true, but the installation should be possible up to version 34.3.0 https://github.com/eerimoq/cantools/commits/master on python2.7

Comment: Yes, but diskcache's setup.py is written for Python3.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer posted the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the problem was with installing the diskcache module,
By default it tried to install a python 3 version supported version
when I manually installed it `pip install diskcache==4.1.0` 
and then installed cantools again it worked.